# How can I alter the submit button text of bulk operations?

Tags: 8

I'm trying to alter the text on the bulk operations submit button. It seems the standard `hook_form_alter()` does not work in this context.

The standard text is *Apply to selected items* and I want to change that for a particular view.

Code:

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-print-selected-pages-page-1') {
    // I can't find the button in $form.
  }
}
```

When I look at the generated source I can see that the bulk operations form has a form ID like `views-exposed-form-print-selected-pages-page-1-asd1235x` that changes between page reloads.

Comment: I remember doing this in Drupal 7 with hook_form_alter() so +1 if there's an alternative. It might be better to include your hook_form_alter() implementation in case there is an issue there.

Comment: I agree with @mradcliffe. Please provide the code you have used rather than saying it does not work.

Comment: form alter should work, but you should also be able to use Interface translation for that. Note that in Drupal 8, you can just enable the locale module and then you can enable translations also for english, with a certain overhead of course (but no more than any non-english site has anyway)

Comment: If I use the Interface translation would that not change the text of all the Bulk operation submit buttons?